# How to persist a Hibernate child entity without loading the parent-side Set collection

Tags: hibernate

We are using Hibernate 3.5.6-Final with Hazelcast 3.6.1  2nd level cache.

### Situation

I have a bi-directional, one-to-many relation between a `Parent` and a `Child` entity with the Hibernate setting `inverse = true`. The entity classes are defined as follows:

```
class Parent {
   Set<Child> children;
   ... // setters, getters, other properties
}

class Child {
   Parent parent;
   ... // setters, getters, other properties       
}
```

The Hibernate mapping of the parent is defined as follows:

```
<set name="children"
     lazy="true"
     inverse="true"
     cascade="all"
     sort="unsorted">
     <cache usage="read-write"/>
     <key column="parent_id"/>
     <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
```

The Hibernate mapping of the child is defined as follows:

```
<many-to-one name="parent"
    class="Parent"
    cascade="none"
    column="parent_id"
    not-null="true"/>
```

The current code now adds a `Child` to the `Parent` as follows:

```
child.setParent(parent);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
```

The problem is that the second line of code causes Hibernate to load *all* children. In our setting this is a very expensive operation as the child entities have eager collections that have entities with eager collections again.

Changing the Hibernate model is currently not an option.

### Question

I changed the above code as follows:

```
child.setParent(parent);
sessionFactory.getCache().evictCollection( "Parent.children", parent.getId() );
```

This worked so far. The apparent problem now is that the `children` collection of the parent in the current session *might* be outdated if it was loaded before the code was executed. I want to ensure that afterwards any call to `parent.getChildren()` returns the up-to-date collection, without actually adding the child explictly to the collection. I actually would like to tell Hibernate to invalidate the collection so that it loads the set again if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I solved it by adding a new method `addChild` to the `Parent` that looks as follows:

```
 public void addChild(Child child) {
     child.setParent(this);
     if (Hibernate.isInitialized(getChildren()) {
         getChildren().add(child);
     } else {
         Hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCache().evictCollection(
             getClass().getName()+".children", this.getId());
     }
 }
```

Thus: if the children have already been loaded for some reason, the new child is added to the children set. This ensures that an already loaded set stays consistent. If the set is *not* loaded yet, I just set the parent to the child and evict the 2nd level cache (that this is needed is described here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/580). As the set is not loaded yet it can also not be inconsistent. When the set is accessed afterwards, Hibernate will load the set including the new child.

Answer (score 5):

There's a better way:

1. You need to make the many-to-one side lazy.

   ```
   <many-to-one name="parent"
       class="Parent"
       cascade="none"
       column="parent_id"
       not-null="true"
       lazy="true"/>
   ```
2. As long as you don't need to fetch the Parent entity in the currently running Persistence Context, you can just fetch a Proxy reference:

   ```
   Parent parentProxy = session.load(Parent.class, parentId);
   ```
3. Now, you can simply create a new child as follows:

   ```
   Child newChild = new Child();
   child.setParent(parentProxy);
   session.persist(newChild);
   ```

Another workaround is as follows:

You don't even fetch a Parent Proxy reference, but instead, you do as follows:

```
Parent parentReference = new Parent();
parentReference.setId(parentId);

Child newChild = new Child();
child.setParent(parentReference);
session.persist(newChild);
```

This way, you don't need to fully fetch the Parent entity if all you need is to persist a Child entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I cannot change the Hibernate mapping definition as mentioned in the question. The second problem is that client code _might_ have loaded the parent and its children already. Not adding the element to the children set could then cause consistency problems

Comment: I know that the post is old, but this is the right answer. The workaround works like a charm. You don't even need to do a select and fetch the parent entity from the database - just create a 'fake' reference that carries the parent's id and set to the child. Perfect!

Comment: Hi @Vlad. Does the Hibernate never update the parent from owning side?

Comment: @Arash Hibernate updates all managed entities that have been modified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vlad. You've created a new `parent` with existing id. Does hibernate set the attributes of the old `parent` entity with that id to default and why if not?

Comment: Either a Proxy or a POJO is enough to set the FK column value, which is exactly what both options are doing here.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Vlad and sorry that i didn't ask my question correctly. If there is an entity with id, `1L` in the DB and i create a new entity instance with that id and persist it via it's child, why doesn't hibernate throw `EntityExistsException`?

Comment: The reason why Hibernate doesn't throw an `EntityExistsException` is that, by default, `persist` doesn't propagate from child entities to parent, and why would it do that? A parent's existence precedes the child, hence there's no reason why a child's entity state change should trigger a parent state change as well.