# Hibernate 4 : avoid loading big collection to add an element - 2nd level cache consistency

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, infinispan

I'm struggling with a performance issue when adding or deleting entities that belong to a one-to-many collection (set) on another entity.

I have the proper many-to-one inverse relationship set.

Let me show you with some code. Here is the `Child` entity :

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "child")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@BatchSize(size = 20)
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dbid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent1_id", nullable = true)
    private Parent1 parent1;

    /** Some other attributes, getters / setters **/
}
```

Here is the `Parent1` class :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "parent1")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@BatchSize(size = 20)
public class Parent1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dbid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();

    /** Some other attributes, getters / setters **/
}
```

I'm currently using EHCache.

Currently, when we create a `Child` that belongs to a `Parent1`, we maintain (as required) the both sides of the relationship by setting the `parent1` attribute of the `Child` and adding the child to the `children` collection.

This causes a fetch of the whole `children` collection and it's our performance bottleneck as :

- it may contain hundreds ouf thousands of entities
- when we add an entity to it, it invalidate the cache so when we perform this operation repeatedly (think of a client adding hundreds of children one by one), each adding re-fetches the collection

My performance concern is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119537/how-to-persist-a-hibernate-child-entity-without-loading-the-parent-side-set-coll/41219637#41219637) and I suppose **the accepted answer could match my requirements**. With some adaptations (how to evict the collection changes from Hibernate 3 to 4), at least regarding performance, it works really well.

I would still like to be sure that it doesn't mess with the 2nd level cache **or anything else**, keeping in mind that all that is done is **inside transactions**.

We catch the potential cache errors caused by the `READ_WRITE` cache strategy (stale state or stale object exceptions, I guess these are first level cache errors ?) and perform rollbacks when they occur (that's the current expected behavior of our app), and it doesn't seem to corrupt the cache further than the first level.

In a near future, we want to go full transactional with Infinispan (so we'll have to use the `TRANSACTIONAL` cache concurrency strategy).

That said, formally, my question is : how can I add / delete a child from the `Parent1`'s `children` collection without loading the collection when it's not in the cache with these constraints :

- with EHCache : it's not a problem to cause a one-time (rare) error that would have no other consequence than a proper rollback, but it must never really corrupt the cache, or break the transactional guarantee.
- ideally I would like the solution to work whatever cache we use (Infinispan for example)

And of course, I'd like to know why any solution (the one from the link above ?) would bring such guarantees.

*Please don't blame me if some annotations are not really relevant (don't hesitate to comment if it's the case ;) ), it's legacy code I'm working on, and I'm still learning. Also maybe I didn't really get all the concepts right and I'll quickly edit my question if needed.*

Comment: FYI, starting with Hibernate 5 Infinispan no longer mandates `TRANSACTIONAL`. It can also work as `READ_WRITE` and `NON_STRICT_READ_WRITE` too.

Comment: WRT your 2nd level cache worries about the solution in the other post, whenever you call evict on a Hibernate cache, it immediately evicts the item/collection independent of the transaction isolation.

Comment: Thanks for your input @GalderZamarreño . I understand that, but I'm not sure if that ensures that my second level cache will behave well (maybe you ar not saying that at all?). Consider the sequence : transaction1 starts a task needing the collection, possibly loading it or not - transaction2 evicts it and adds an element but doesn't commit yet - transaction1 finishes its work and commits - transaction2 finishes and commits. Then I wonder if anything could go wrong. I know I'm not really clear about what precisely could go wrong because I miss experience about these subjects.

Comment: The cache is irrelevant in that case, the source of truth is the DB, so it's up to the DB and your settings to decide if that combination is valid. I'm not huge expert on HB/JPA but I feel tx2 would fail since the collection has changed since it started the tx. Might depend on the isolation level. You can always test such scenarios yourself ;)

Comment: Well my concern is not that the transaction would fail as we catch this properly, but rather if I would introduce a persistent cache corruption or not. I guess I'll have to force some collisions and try ;) Thx @GalderZamarreño !

Comment: The cache does what the DB tells it to. If you evict from cache, even better because there's nothing to keep consistent in the cache.