# Is it possible in Hibernate to add/remove children of a OneToMany relationship without loading all the children?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, scalability

For the following domain:

```
class Parent {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
   Set <Child> children;
)

class Child {
   @ManyToOne
   Parent parent;
   ... // setters, getters, other properties       
}
```

I'm looking for a way to add child entities, without Lazy initializing children in the Parent object.

Ex:

```
child.set(parent) // is fine, since Parent is pretty lightweight.

parent.getChildren().add(child) // No good, since in this case it will attempt to 
//load all the children of a Parent object.
```

From the first glance it felt like something that should have been easily achievable since in order to add a child all you need is just a parent id and an SQL insert statement to the Child table.
However when it comes to hibernate nothing is simple (In fact it’s true for everything that uses caching) :-)

We are trying to scale a legacy application that was initially written to support tens of children,  but over time evolved to operate with thousands of children now and as you can imagine that doesn’t scale well, since every time we need to add a child, we need to load the entire group in memory first what results in O(N) time and  O(N) space complexity (where N is a total number of children).

Have anyone run into a similar problem? Is there a way to solve it in hibernate, or hibernate is just not the best framework to use for this use case? How have you tackled it? Or any ideas, share of experience will be helpful.

I run into the following discussion:
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119537/how-to-persist-a-hibernate-child-entity-without-loading-the-parent-side-set-coll"
That felt a bit sketchy to me since evicting cache might cause concurrency issues (especially when code will run on multiple servers)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible.

```java
class Parent {
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = PERSIST)
   Set <Child> children = new HashSet<>();

   public void addChild(Child child) {
      child.setParent(this);
      children.add(child);
   }
}
...

parent.addChild(child);
```

In this case, lazy initialization of `Parent.children` won't be triggered. You can check it out by enabling SQL logging (`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`).

### EDIT 1

If you store `children` as `Set`, then you should override `equals` and `hashCode` [correctly](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Note that Hibernate entity is not a regular DTO. So, generating default implementation won't work properly. According to Hibernate Specification entity should not change its identity (`equals/hashCode` result) through all the lifecycle.

Here is the example.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZZ_CHILD")
public class Child {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Child)) {
            return false;
        }
        Child other = (Child) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, other.id) && id != null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Or you can replace `Set` with `List` and everything is going to work without additional `select` as well.

[image]

Comment: Hm... are you sure about that? I'm seeing select from child table by parent id:

hibernate.SQL - select children0_.parent_PARENT_ID as parent_p3_141_0_, children0_.CHILD_ID as child_id1_141_0_, children0_.CHILD_ID as child_id1_141_1_, children0_.NAME as name2_141_1_, children0_.parent_PARENT_ID as parent_p3_141_1_ from ZZ_CHILD children0_ where children0_.parent_PARENT_ID=?

Comment: Wrapped my trials in a simple spring boot application and pushed it to git:
https://github.com/rbicherschii/stack-overflow/tree/main/parentChildTest

You can run it as:
./mvnw test

And see the hibernate log:
########################################################## RUNNING TEST CASE

########################################################## COMPLETING TEST CASE

Comment: @BickerskyRoman thank for detailed information. I found the source of the issue. I updated the answer

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks Semyon! Changing it to List definitely made it not to do the extra select! So lazy initialization is happening only when you are trying to iterate through the list not just getting an instance of the list, good to know!!!

Comment: Can you think of anything that can be done to remove a child without lazy initializing the entire list of children?

Comment: @BickerskyRoman I think the easiest way is to delete child by id directly

Comment: @BickerskyRoman does that answering question? If so, could you mark my post as an answer, please?

Comment: @SemyonKirekov, this guy got his answer and vanished! not bothering to mark the post as the answer. He is one of a kid. I upvoted your answer however I found a problem in the case of removing an item from the collection. It seems that lazy fetching does not work in this case.

Comment: @Mr.Q Thank you! But what do you mean by "not working"? Can you provide a reproducible example to me?

Comment: @SemyonKirekov as I previously said, remove operation fetches all the Child entities and does not work in a lazy manner. Now I noticed that you have already mentioned this in your GitHub commit message  "Adding test case for removeChild (but it's failing)"  But in general it is a good solution.